# How to differentiate Null or Empty ? on what criteria Null and Empty treated?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, programming-languages, null

Hi all of SO users I'm having little confusion with understanding null and Empty. 
I know null is special case, which is not equal to itself. I want to know how to determine  that it is null, on what basis you are telling it is null, and the same for empty also

1. Is it based on memory allocation or what?
2. If then how memory allocated for null.
3. If its empty then what crieteria suits for it to be as "EMPTY".

Just I want know how the compiler come to know it is NULL or Empty.

Comment: "null is not equal to itself", that only applies to SQL, not C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`null` is a special reference that means 'not referencing anything'

Empty only applies to collections (and a string is a collection of char). It means there is a valid collection but it contains no (0) elements.

When returning a collection it is usually better to return an empty collection instead of null.

When receiving a collection, decide whether `null` should be treated as an empty collection. This depends on the situation, agreements and promises made etc.

> i know null is special case, which is not equal to itself

Not entirely true. `null == null` is always true.

Comment: ok. one more thing Can u tell me how the compiler come to know whether it is null or empty ? on which basis it differniate the both .

Comment: Nothing special... `null` is a special (pre-defined) reference. An empty collection is referenced by a valid non-null reference and has Count==0